# Direct3D 11 depth buffer result in black screen

Tags: c++, direct3d, depth-buffer

I tried to implement the depth buffer in Direct3D 11, but it turns out to not be as easy as I fought. Here's my problem : Whenever I'm calling this function :

```
m_DeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_RTV, m_DepthStencilView);
```

With the 3rd parameter as my depth stencil view, I see nothing in my window ; everything is black. If I put nullptr then all my geometries are rendered without any depth testing (like it was before I atempt to implement depth). Here's how I'm creating my depth buffer and my depth stencil view :

```
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthBufferDesc;
ZeroMemory(&depthBufferDesc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
depthBufferDesc.Width = iwidth;
depthBufferDesc.Height = iheight;
depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;

hr = m_Device->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, nullptr, &m_DepthStencilBuffer);

hr = m_Device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_DepthStencilBuffer, nullptr, &m_DepthStencilView);
```

I search for quite some time to find the solution but I didn't help me. I also checked the viewport but it doesn't work. I also clean up the view every frame.

Can you help me out please ? I'll appreciate it :) Thanks.

Comment: Normally default depth stencil state should be less read write, which should fit your use case. Maybe try to enable debug device to see if you have any runtime warning/errors

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to clear your depth buffer to 1.0 before trying to use it.

Comment: I don't have the code anymore but I'm sure I didn't forget to do so.